# How do you zoom into a symbol with KEY_UP and zoom out with KEY_DOWN?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Here's one way to do it with the mouse wheel:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, zoom);
function zoom(e:MouseEvent) {
    square.z+=20*e.delta;
}
```

How would you go about doing it with KEY_UP and KEY_DOWN?

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, zoom);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, zoom);
function zoom(e:MouseEvent):void{
}
```

Comment: it depends on how much you wanna zoom on one press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, no, this one will not work

KEY_UP is fired when a pressed key is released. It can be ANY key.
Similarly, KEY_DOWN for when a key is pressed

What you REALLY have to do:

```
//add event handler for key release
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
//Key release event handler
function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.UP) { //up key is pressed
        zoomIn();
    } else if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.DOWN) { //down key is pressed
        zoomOut();
    }
}

function zoomIn():void{
    square.z+=5;
}

function zoomOut():void{
    square.z-=5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this one will work:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, zoomIn);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, zoomOut);
function zoomIn(e:MouseEvent):void{
    square.z+=5;
}
function zoomOut(e:MouseEvent):void{
    square.z-=5;
}
```